# Django escape filepath "\\\\" instead of "\\"

Tags: python, django

I use Windows 7 64b, Python 3.5.1 32b, Django 1.9.2 and WAMP 2.5.

I try to open file:

```
  path = ''.join([config_object.bat_files_path, os.sep, config_object.id, ".bat"])
  with open(path, 'w') as file:
       file.write(command)
```

When I use development server everything is ok, but when I use WAMP, an error occur:

```
File "C:\\wamp\\www\\xxx\\tasks.py", line 254, in create_bat_file
with open(path), 'w' as file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'X:\\\\Auto\\\\xxx\\\\bat_files\\\\01.bat'
```

But I'm sure, that path is correct, because when I test it:

```
print(os.path.is_file(path))
```

it returned True. Path is:

```
'X:\\Auto\\xxx\\bat_files\\01.bat'
```

So, why I have 4 slashes? I have tried to replace them, but at the end path is always splitted by 4 slashes. Any idea, why is that?

Comment: What's the value of `config_object.bat_files_path`?

Comment: It's a path in database (as string). Exactly: "X:\Auto\xxx\bat_files"

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but you could use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) (plus [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)). `path = os.path.join(config_object.bat_files_path, '{}.bat'.format(config_object.id))`.

Comment: Are you sure that there are only single backslashes in your database? Please do a `print(repr(config_object.bat_files_path))` to see the real content.

Comment: @Matthias: result: 'X:\\\\Auto\\\\xxx\\\\bat_files', and without repr: 'X:\\Auto\\xxx\\bat_files', i don't know why, because in DB i entered path with one backslash... In Django admin also is visilble one backslash as a separator.

Comment: Maybe it is related that I have Python 32b. and Windows 64b.?

Comment: Python32 should run without problems on Windows64 - at least it does for me. So if it is really only one backslash in the database something must happen to this string on it's way from the database to the variable.

Comment: But on Django development server everything works fine. It's strange...